# Merging CSV Files With decimal places

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

I have two CSV files like:

> First File
>
> Value1;Value2
>
> 123;456
>
> Second File
>
> Value1;Value2
>
> 789;101112

[powershell]
when i do
`dir * | import-csv | export-csv all.csv` ... the Output, opened in Excel is like

> Value1;Value2
>
> 123;456
>
> 789;101112

all fine

but when i do

> File1
>
> value1;value2
>
> 123;2,34
>
> File2
>
> value1;value2
>
> 567;8,910

the Output is like

> value1;value2
>
> 123;4
>
> 567;8

is it possible to get a result like

> value1;value2
>
> 123;2,34
>
> 567;8,910

?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem rises from list separator character and decimal separator character. In the en-us locale, comma `,` is used to separate list members from each other and period `.` is used to separate decimals. In many locales, comma is used as decimal separator, so list separator tends to be semicolon `;`.

Without knowing your locale, I'd hazard a guess that `Import-CSV` and `Export-CSV` are guessing what delimiters are to be used. This doesn't quite succeed, so the outcome is invalid.

Since Powershell 2.0 both cmdlets support explicit delimiter specification. Add `-Delimiter ';'` switch to both input and output commands.